# datepicker is always 0 on database codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I have date picker and it's always `0000-00-00 00:00:00` on database

Here's my code

```
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-4">
   <div class="form-group">
       <input class="datepicker" name="datepicker" width="330" placeholder="Birthday" />
   </div>
</div>
```

and on my js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
      uiLibrary: 'bootstrap'
    });
});
```

and save it like this

```
$datepicker=$this->input->post('datepicker');
$this->main_model->save_records($datepicker);
```

can someone help me.

Comment: what value passed in `$datepicker` ?

Comment: @DevsiOdedra string '09/03/2019'

Comment: Try `09-03-2019` (`$this->main_model->save_records(str_replace('/','-', $datepicker));`)

Comment: you should pass date as `2019-03-09` because in your database table you have date formate as `Y-m-d H:i:s` so pass date as per db formate.

Comment: @zanderwar no luck sir

Comment: $datepicker = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($this->input->post('datepicker')));

Answer (score -3, accepted):

[image]

[image]

AND you can save database by way:

```js
$("#validityDueDate").on("dp.change", function () {
    var valueChangeValidityDueDate = $('#validityDueDate').data("DateTimePicker").date().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss');
    console.log("value::", valueChangeValidityDueDate); // using value to save into database
}
```

Comment: Please don't post code as images. Code should be copy/pasted into the answer itself. If you put code as images, people can't copy it and it won't be searchable.